# How do you say, "Sorry, we're closed for today."?

Tags: english-to-japanese, formality, greetings

I am still studying Nihongo and I'm literally at the very basic part of characters but I had to say to a customer that our shop was closed for today, and I ended up embarrassing myself. Please help me with how to formally say "Sorry, we're closed for today." to a customer. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking to someone, you can say

- 「すみません、本日{ほんじつ}の営業{えいぎょう}は終了{しゅうりょう}いたしました」
- "Sumimasen, honjitsu no eigyou wa shuuryou itashimashita"
- Sorry, we have already finished doing business today

Alternatively, you can say (or leave a sign on the door/outside)

- 「本日{ほんじつ}は閉店{へいてん}しました」
- "Honjitsu wa heiten shimashita"
- We have closed today

And it should be fine, according to an answer on chiebukuro. However, there is a small chance that it gets interpreted as "Store has permanently closed" https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1394257368

Another common sign to leave on your door / outside is simply
「営{えい}業{ぎょう}終{しゅう}了{りょう}」(Can simply be translated as "Closed" (for the day))

A good sign example can be viewed here: https://harigamiya.jp/item/sorry-we-are-closed.html

(Text from image)

```
営業終了
本日の営業は終了いたしました
またお越しをお待ちしております
SORRY WE ARE CLOSED
```

(Translated)

```
Closed
We have finished doing business for the day
We await your next visit
SORRY WE ARE CLOSED
```